# Why ARIMA model not accepting the day of the week variables for seasonality period 7

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a daily data for doing forecasting.

My series getting frequency/period 7 from findfrequency() function from forecast package.
But when i used day of the week variable like Monday to saturday variable as a regressor in a ARIMA model its gives error.

```
Urban_UH_RB001001_train_arima<-Arima((Urban_UH_RB001001_train_ts),order=c(4,0,3),xreg=Urban_UH_RB001001_train[,c("monday_flag","Tuesday_flag","Wednesday_flag","salary_day_flag","long_week","Nov_flag","week1_flag"),with=FALSE],seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=7))
Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim
```

As per my daily data those variable are most important to capture the day effect in my model.

So can anyone suggest me why this happen with Arima model?

Comment: How did you code the Day of week variable?

Comment: Day of the week variable created in my data set through column date.

Comment: Date is represented in R via some special structure which arima function do not understand. Maybe you should construct a dummy?

Comment: @Kjetil b , I already create a 6 dummy variable in my data sets like Monday to saturday. but when i used those variable in my model with periodicity 7 it gives error.